# Does webpack have something like a libraryTarget of "function"?

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I would like my webpack-compiled library to be the return value of a function.

Webpack will let me compile my output and [assign the result to a variable](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-a-variable) by setting the `libraryTarget` in my config file to `var`, giving me something like this:

```
var MyLibrary = function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var o=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,expo...;
```

If I simply include this output file, as-is, in my webpage, I end up with `window.MyLibrary`, which is not exactly what I was after but getting closer.

I've got an advanced use-case (one that's difficult to fully explain without writing a book about it). Suffice to say, I would prefer to "initialize" the library via a function, like this:

```
function init(){
    return function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var o=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,expo...;
}
```

I had hoped to find a [`libraryTarget` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget) along these lines, but alas there does not appear to be one in the docs.

Am I just supposed to use other build tools to concatenate my output file into another file, à la a template? Or is there a feature within webpack that I've overlooked? Perhaps this result is achievable through the use of several other advanced features in concert? I'm not averse to a plugin, but obviously I'd prefer native functionality.

---

Here's a more thorough example of what I'd like to accomplish.

### Current Code

**utils.js**

```
let d = new Date();

export default {
    getInitDateTime(id){
        return d;
    }
};
```

**lib.js**

```
import utils from "./utils.js";

export let lib = ({
    test: function(){
        return utils.getInitDateTime();
    }
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './lib.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        libraryExport: 'lib',
        library: 'mylib',
    }
};
```

**bundle.js** (compiled)

```
var mylib=function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var u=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(u.exports,u,u.exports,n),u.l=!0,u.exports}return n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=0)}([function(e,t,n){"use strict";n.r(t);let r=new Date;var u={getInitDateTime:e=>r};n.d(t,"lib",function(){return o});let o={test:function(){return u.getInitDateTime()}}}]).lib;
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
        <script>
            var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
            var root = document.getElementById('root');

            btn.onclick = function(){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'Test: ' + mylib.test();
                root.appendChild( div );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you click the button three times you get something like:

> Test: Tue May 08 2018 10:28:41 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>   Test: Tue May 08 2018 10:28:41 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>   Test: Tue May 08 2018 10:28:41 GMT-0400 (EDT)

### Desired Result

Here's how I'd *like* use my library in `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
        <script>
            var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
            var root = document.getElementById('root');

            btn.onclick = function(){

                // ******************************************
                // Create a new instance of the library:
                var mylib = initmylib();
                // ******************************************

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'Test: ' + mylib.test();
                root.appendChild( div );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So if I click my button three times, I get something like:

> Test: Tue May 08 2018 10:40:41 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>   Test: Tue May 08 2018 10:40:42 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>   Test: Tue May 08 2018 10:40:43 GMT-0400 (EDT)

I can already accomplish this by manually modifying my `bundle.js` like so:

```
function initmylib(){
    return function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var u=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(u.exports,u,u.exports,n),u.l=!0,u.exports}return n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=0)}([function(e,t,n){"use strict";n.r(t);let r=new Date;var u={getInitDateTime:e=>r};n.d(t,"lib",function(){return o});let o={test:function(e,t){return u.getInitDateTime()}}}]).lib;
}
```

But this requires either manual modification or additional build steps. I'd like to know if webpack can do something like this on it's own.

### Yes, this MCVE is Trivial... My Real Library is Not.

Obviously this particular library is trivial and I could easily refactor it to behave as desired. The problem is that my real library is about 5-6 years old, has hundreds of thousands of lines of code spread across hundreds of files and is actively used within an existing product. I'm trying to migrate it slowly and I want to use webpack to do it. Refactoring *everything* up-front is going to be too time-consuming. If I can simply wrap the bundle in a function (as demonstrated) it would solve a lot of problems very quickly.

I can use extra build steps to accomplish my goal... I just want to know if webpack can do it for me.

Comment: have you tried make the export of your module as a function and setting libraryTarget to var?

Comment: Part of the problem is that module exports are shared by all importers, which is great... But, if I want a second instance of my library with its own copies/instances, then I'd have to significantly increase the complexity of my library to support multiple instances. By wrapping everything in a function, I can take advantage of JS scoping and get that behavior "for free".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think webpack can automatically call the function for you. The first time webpack see your module, it get the export and cache it. On subsequent imports, it returns from cache.

But you can try something like this:

```
  export default function createLibraryInstance () {
    let myPrivateValue = 1;

    return {
      getValue: function () {
        return myPrivateValue;
      }
    }
  }
```

then in webpack config:

```
  {
    output: {
      library: 'createLibraryInstance',
      libraryTarget: 'var'
    }
  }
```

use it like this:

```
  let myInstance = window.createLibraryInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks... I've updated my question to demonstrate my desired outcome and to explain why this approach is not ideal.